# Trying to modify wordpress template

Tags: wordpress, layout

I often get stuck when it comes to wordpress as I'm used to being able to move everything around. Below is my domain name and shows the responsive theme that I'm trying to modify:

http://govansoven.co.uk/

Now I want to make the header full width and keep the container at 960px so I planned to simply move the  outside of the container div. However I can't find the file that shows this code. I can't see it within the editor of wordpress (i've checked the obvious ones index.php, header.php etc) So will it be hidden with the FTP?

Comment: We're going to need more than that. We can't just guess what your files look like. But if I _had_ to guess, it _has_ to be in the `header.php` file. Would you mind double-checking?

Answer (score 0):

the container will probably be in page.php